# using the ! (NOT) operand in Linq's Where() method for c#

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I have a large collection of fruits in a database.

Some of those fruits have not been finished i.e. they are missing some details about them such as colour, texture, size etc. In this case the missing attribute is the colour.

Using linq's `Where()` method I'm pretty sure I can filter out all of those
 fruits which don't have a colour and return them as a collection of
 fruits.

the problem is I'm not sure how the syntax works and for some reason i
 get the issue where although `fruits` and `fruitfinder.fruits` are both
 `Fruit` collections there is an implicit casting issue.

```
FruitCollection fruits = null;

//Initializing the fruits collection here
//What I want is to only retrive the fruits which have a color
fruits = fruitFinder.fruits.Where( f => f.color != null );
```

This is just an example but an answer provided here keeps the question generic and can answer my specific problem.

Comment: `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<Fruit>` not a `FruitCollection`. Do you need a `FruitCollection`? If so, provide  a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<Fruit>`. Then use a `foreach` there to fill your collection.

Comment: @Tim thanks for the input, I went a similar way by converting to list and passing the list as a parameter.

Comment: Perhaps subjective but i prefer a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<Fruit>` since that allows any kind of fruits as input (f.e. `Fruit[]`). Then you could use `fruits.ToList()` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fruits` will be `IEnumerable<Fruit>` and not a `FruitCollection` like so:

```
IEnumerable<Fruit> fruits = fruitFinder.fruits.Where( f => f.color != null );
```

I'm making the assumption the fruit type is `Fruit` but you get the idea.

Comment: Can i then cast the IEnumerable a a fruit Collection?

Comment: No. But do you really need to?

Comment: @KyleT No :-) But normally `SomethingCollection` have a constructor that accept an `IEnumerable` and/or an `AddRange(...)`

Comment: Yeah if its possible Id really like to be able to create a collection from the IEnumerable as the collection type is reused throughout the rest of the application. Thanks for the input this has really helped me to see what i was doing wrong.